# Mojolicious wildcard placeholders and question mark

Tags: perl, url-routing, mojolicious

The wildcard placeholder (*) is said to match absolutely everything.
But I'm afraid that it doesn't...

I have a webservice with the following method:

```
get '/*param' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $param = $self->stash('param');
  $self->app->log->debug($param);
}
```

When i query my service with: http://localhost:3000/search
then the method logs "search" which is ok
but
when i query my service with: http://localhost:3000/search?page=1
then the method also logs "search" which is not ok IMO

I also tried replacing

```
get '/*param' => sub {
```

with

```
get '/:param' => [param => qr/.*/] => sub {
```

but the result is the same.

Does anybody know of a way around this?
Or should I file this as a bug?

Regards,
Lorenzo

**UPDATE**
for people with the same problem, I've worked around this issue like this:

```
get '/*path' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $path = $self->stash('path');

  my @params = $self->param;
  if (scalar @params > 0) {
    $path .= '?';
    foreach my $param (@params) {
      $path .= $param . '=' . $self->param($param) . '&';
    }
    $path = substr($path, 0, length($path) - 1);
  }

  $self->app->log->debug($path);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?page= its not url.

Its param.

So no any bugs here.
you have 'search' in $param.
And $page=1 in stash.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're saying Korjavin, but the wildcard placeholder should match _everything_ (according to the docs) and it doesn't. I'm also sure that the "?page=1" part is not elsewhere on the stash. I added "$self->app->log->debug(Dumper $self->stash);" and I couldn't find the rest of the url (i.e. ?page=1) anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

I think [Korjavin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311596/268539) is right, that's expected behavior. Looks like "page=1" as a parameter and should be in $stash->param('page'). See [GET-POST-parameters in ::Lite](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious::Lite#GET-POST-parameters)

If it does not work, maybe renaming the "param" placeholder to something else helps? Maybe it's a name-clash.

Comment: It seems you're right. I did find 'page' in $self->param. But IMO this is still a bug. If the docs state that a wildcard matches (and I'm quoting) _absolutely everything_ then it should really match absolutely everything!

Comment: yeah, the docs are better now, but still far from perfect. Guess you could send a patch request on github

Answer (score 1):

The request parameters wouldn't be in the stash.

They're in

$self->req->params

So

```
    my $params = $self->req->params->to_hash;
    $self->app->log->debug(Dumper $params);
```

Should allow you to see the information you're after